# Ports not picked up ansible docker module

Tags: docker, ansible

I am using ansible (2.0) [docker module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/docker_module.html) to start a jboss docker container. My playbook looks as follows:

```
- name: Pull aplication jboss container
  docker:
    name: jboss
    image: jboss/wildfly
    state: started
    pull: always
    ports:
    - "9990:9990"
    - "8080:8080"
    command: "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
```

I want to mimic the command shown in the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/):

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0
```

If I execute the playbook, and run docker ps, my ports are not bound to 9990, only 8080:

```
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

If I do not use the playbook, and only run my docker container using the aforementioned command that I want to mimic, I can see both ports:

```
0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9990->9990/tcp
```

How would I use the docker module to bind both 8080 and 9990 ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up manually exposing the both ports to make this work, via the expose command:

```
- name: Pull aplication jboss container
  docker:
    name: jboss
    image: jboss/wildfly
    state: started
    pull: always
    expose:
    - 9990
    - 8080
    ports:
    - "9990:9990"
    - "8080:8080"
    command: "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0"
```

I am not sure if that is the best answer, but for now, it is solving the problem of the ports not being exposed.

Comment: Yes, that is what the cocumentation says. You either need to `EXPOSE` those ports in Dockerfile or use `expose:` argument to docker module in playbook.